# Symfony app_dev.php install \DOMDomain error

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I have installed Symfony on localhost under CentOS under VMware player. (Windows 7, 32 bit)
My PHP version is 5.3.3.   CentOS is 6.5.  VMware player is 6.0.1.

When I attempt to connect with  `localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php` I get the following error

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DOMDocument" from the
>   global namespace in
>   /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php
>   line 47.

Did you forget a use statement for this class?

line 47 is

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
```

I get 102 hits when I grep "DOMDocument".

Most hits display

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
```

or

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
```

I had previously installed Symfony on an external server following the same script and was able to exercise `app_dev.php` without problem. (FreeBSD)

What is the difference between `new \DOMDocument();`  and `new DOMDocument();`.
I am a JavaScript and PHP novice.   Does anyone know what I should do to correct this ? or some clues as to how to trouble-shoot ?

Comment: on FreeBSD, the extension is called php70-dom (for php7)

Answer (score 11):

Running **yum install php-xml** on CentOS 6.5 solved the problem for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer and show be marked as such.

Comment: Solved my problem with a clear instalation on linux mint (using apt-get instead of yum)

Answer (score 3):

The backslash (`new \DomDocument()`) is required when you are loading a class from the global namespace from inside another namespace. In other words, if you used `namespace <something>` in the top of your file, you will have to use `new \DomDocument()` to load `DomDocument` from the global namespace. If you are in the global namespace (the default, if you haven't explicitly declared a namespace), you can use `new DomDocument()` directly.

If you're getting the error both with the backslash and without it, it's because you're missing a PHP extension: `php-xml`. Just add `extension=dom.so` to your php.ini. The extension is bundled with PHP by default.

Run web/config.php to check what's missing.

Comment: Hello Pedro.  Thanks for the quick answer.  I will make thay change and try again.  Thank you.

Comment: Hello Pedro.   I made the change to /etc/php.ini     I placed the line "extension=dom.so" right at the top of the .ini file, saved, and re-booted CentOS.    I still get the same error.  Any other suggestions ?   Regards, Lorne

Comment: I also ran the config.php.   One suggestion is to upgrade to php 5.3.4 or greater.  Could this be my problem ?  Regards,  Lorne.

Comment: Hi Pedro !                                                          OK, here is what finally worked.                                     "yum install php-xml".     this added the required module and created "/etc/php.d/dom.ini"  which contained     "extension=dom.so".