# Attempted to load class "XmlUtils" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Config\Util"

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, silex

When building a simple site with Silex and Symfony components, I receive the following error after installing the `FormServiceProvider` service:

> **ClassNotFoundException in XliffFileLoader.php line 54:**
>
> Attempted to load class "XmlUtils" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Config\Util".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

The template is here:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p>By {{ page.author }}, published on {{ page.publishedAt|date('m/d/Y') }}</p>
    <pre>{{ page.content }}</pre>
    <hr/>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_body(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I followed the install directions here:

https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/form.html

I've read a number of other questions, most of which talk about a missing global namespace identifier (`\DomDocument` instead of `DomDocument`, which inherits the local namespace), or that `php-xml` is not installed, or that there's a missing configuration. Those are not the issues here, but here is one that covers two of those three:

[Symfony app_dev.php install \DOMDomain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918356/symfony-app-dev-php-install-domdomain-error/21935670)

And here are the configuration calls:

```
$this->app->register(new ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$this->app->register(new LocaleServiceProvider());
$this->app->register(new TranslationServiceProvider(), [
    'locale_fallbacks' => ['en'],
    'translator.messages' => [],
    'translator.domains' => [],
]);
$this->app->register(new AssetServiceProvider());
$this->app->register(new TwigServiceProvider(), [
    'twig.path' => self::TEMPLATE_DIR
]);
$this->app->register(new FormServiceProvider());
$this->app->register(new MonologServiceProvider());
$this->app->register(new HttpFragmentServiceProvider());
```

The last two were the ones suggested as being the culprit based on configuration errors.

How is this error resolved in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is hinted by looking at the file specified:

```
private function extract($resource, MessageCatalogue $catalogue, $domain)
{
    try {
        $dom = XmlUtils::loadFile($resource);
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        throw new InvalidResourceException(sprintf('Unable to load "%s": %s', $resource, $e->getMessage()), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }
```

Line 54 is the fourth line starting with `$dom`. PhpStorm showed that the following two `use` statements were not referencing anything:

```
use Symfony\Component\Config\Util\XmlUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;
```

Which led me to wonder where that came from, leading to the `symfony/config` component. I went back to the Silex `FormServiceProvider` documentation and remembered running this line:

```
composer require symfony/validator symfony/config
```

Note the second in the list. Either I forgot to type that or (as I recall) I *did* type it and it didn't install. Maybe it threw an error and I didn't catch it? I don't know. However, if you're getting this error in a project using Symfony components, check to make sure the Config Component is installed.

Comment: just ran into the same problem. The symfony/config component is used by the symfony/translation, but is only require as "require-dev". I don't geht why it isnt a regular dependency, if it is used normaly..